# Magento1 compilation breaks shopping cart

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart, compilation

Using Magento version 1.9.3.1 on a live store setup. When compilation is enabled, the shopping cart gives a blank screen. The actual checkout page loads fine, but the shopping cart is blank

More info on the problem below:

https://www.iweb.co.uk/2012/02/fix-magento-cartcheckout-blank-page-with-compilation-enabled/

But the solution proposed in above post, doesn't work for us. We already have persistent shopping cart disabled. We've tried disabling any plugin that is related to the cart or checkout process, but still blank page. Obviously not able to get any log errors.

Any suggestions on how to debug or find solution? Thanks.

Comment: Do you need compilation on?  Turn it off.

Comment: Not a particularly helpful comment... yes I need to turn it on, hence the post. I obviously have it turned off just now while it is breaking the shopping cart page.

Comment: Sorry about that comment.  It seems I am very biased when it comes to compilation. I usually test compilation on a dev site before using it for the production. More often enough it causes a lot of errors and I just disable it. The persistent shopping cart connection seems to be inconsistent and only a minor connection to the error you are experiencing. If the compilation process is producing errors then I suggest you keep it off until you find the true cause of the error.  Have you checked the error logs to see what is causing it?

Comment: We have already turned it off. As post says, we are not getting any log errors. Very hard to debug. I've always seen improvements in speed with compilation enabled in other setups we've worked on. We've inherited this one after 2 previous agencies have been at it. The site is littered with redundant plugins. We are disabling the ones we know are safe and not used. But having already disabled all non core Magento extensions, the compilation still doesn't work when enabled.

Comment: Any system.log is generate ??

Comment: A couple suggestions to cover your ground: check the website/store scope to make sure that persistence isn't enabled in any of those scopes. Turn off merge js and merge css. Make sure logging is enabled. Check the console for any js or network errors. Turn on developer mode and enable php errors (uncomment `ini_set('display_errors'), 1);` in index.php). Flush all your cache. If you have something like redis, try flushing it from the command line.

Comment: Thanks Joe. Tried all of that, but no change, still just blank white page with no errors and nothing in log files. I want to change back to the Magento default theme to see if that aids, but we have server issue with firewall, moving to new hosting within 48 hours so will retry the above later this week.